# Generalising the recursion theorem to well-founded posets

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, transfinite-recursion

The recursion theorem states the following.

> Suppose $(A,\preccurlyeq)$ is a chain with order type $\omega$. Let $X$ be any set, let $x\in X$ and let $g\colon X\times A \to X$ be a function. Then there exists a unique function $f\colon A\to X$ such that
> $$f(a) = \begin{cases}
>          \hfil x\hfil     & \text{if $a=\min A$}\\
>          g(f(t),a)   & \text{if $a=\operatorname{succ}(t)$}.
>      \end{cases} $$

(E.g., for the factorial function, we put $A=\mathbb N=X$, $x=1$ and $g(m,n)=mn$.)

Now if we instead have a poset $(A,\preccurlyeq)$ which is well-founded, we can partition it so that the classes of the partition form a chain which has order type $\omega$. Indeed, define the idea of a "minimal set" as follows.

> Let $(A,\preccurlyeq)$ be a poset. The *minimal set* of a subset $B\subseteq A$, denoted $M_\preccurlyeq(B)$ or just $M(B)$, is the set defined by
> $$M(B):= \{b\in B : \text{there is no $m\in B$ such that $m\preccurlyeq b$}\}.$$

Then the desired partition of $A$ is
\begin{align*}
        A_1 &= M(A)\\
        A_2 &= M(A\smallsetminus A_1) \\
        A_3 &= M(A\smallsetminus (A_1\cup A_2)) \\
        &\kern6pt\vdots\\
        A_{n+1} &= M(A\smallsetminus(A_1\cup \cdots\cup A_n))\\
        &\kern6pt\vdots
    \end{align*}
**My question is**: can we state a version of the recursion theorem for this set $A$, according to this partial order?

For instance, an example which comes to mind is the binomial coefficients,
$$c(n,k) = \begin{cases}
   \hfil 1 \hfil & \text{if $(n,k)\in A_1$}\\
   \hfil c(n-1,k-1) + c(n-1,k) & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
Here we have $A=\{(n,m)\in\mathbb N^2 : m\leqslant n\}$, and we are ordering it in the following way:

- for any $n\in\mathbb N$, $(n,0) \preccurlyeq a$ for all $a\in A$
- for any $n\in\mathbb N$, $(n,n) \preccurlyeq a$ for all $a\in A$
- for any $n,k,\ell\in\mathbb N$, $(n,k) \preccurlyeq (n+1,\ell)$.

This captures the natural order implicit in Pascal's triangle:

[image]

Note that $A_1$ contains precisely base cases, and then the rest of the sets are such that we can define $c(n,k)$ at the $A_k$th level using its values at the previous levels.

Another example is remainder upon division:

$$r(n,d) = \begin{cases}
        \hfil n \hfil & \text{if $0\leqslant n\leqslant d$}\\
        r(n-d,d) & \text{if $n > d$}\\
        r(n+d,d) & \text{if $n < 0$}
    \end{cases}$$

Here the set is $A=\mathbb Z\times \mathbb N$, and the order is

- $(n,d)\preccurlyeq a$ if $0\leqslant n\leqslant d$ for any $d$
- $(n,d)\preccurlyeq (x,y)$ if $|ny|\leqslant|xd|$.

If it is to be formulated similarly, I was thinking the theorem would look something like this:

> Suppose $(A,\preccurlyeq)$ is a poset where $\preccurlyeq$ is well-founded, and $\{A_1, A_2,\dots\}$ is the partition of "minimal sets" induced by $\preccurlyeq$. Let $X$ be any set, let $x_a\in X$ for each $a\in A_1$, and let $g\colon A\times X^? \to X$ be a function. Then there exists a unique function $f\colon A\to X$ such that
> $$f(a) = \begin{cases} 
>   \hfil x_a\hfil & \text{if $a\in A_1$}\\
>   g(a, f(a_1),f(a_2),\dots) & \text{if $a\in A_k$ and $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_{k-1} = \{a_1,a_2,\dots\},$} 
> \end{cases}$$

i.e., the base cases are all for $a\in A_1$, and the inductive case is allowed to use the value of $f$ at any of the $a$ in the previous sets $A_1,\dots,A_{k-1}$. But this formulation doesn't feel as succinct as it could be, and also the arity of $g$ varies depending on which $A_k$ our $a$ lies in. It also doesn't feel like it captures cleanly the examples I had in mind; I can't clearly tell you what $g$ to take.

I appreciate any help with formulating this theorem. I want to have a general theorem which justifies "definition by recursion" for any well-founded poset.

Comment: In general it is not necessarily the case that every element of $A$ is in some $A_k$; you may have to continue the process transfinitely. (For instance, if $A$ is well-ordered, each $A_k$ is a singleton and $A$ might be longer than $\omega$.)

Comment: @EricWofsey You are right about this, but we can assume $A$ is countable for the sake of the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to get a total order associated to your partial order to make sense of recursion.  Indeed, you don't even need to have a partial order!  Here is a simple way to formulate recursion with respect to any well-founded relation.

> **Theorem**: Let $X$ be a set and let $<$ be a well-founded relation on $X$ (i.e., for any nonempty subset $A\subseteq X$, there exists $a\in A$ such that $b\not< a$ for all $b\in A$).  Let $F:X\times V\to V$ be any (class) function.  Then there exists a unique function $f$ on $X$ such that for each $x\in X$, $f(x)=F(x,f|_{I(x)})$ where $I(x)=\{y\in X:y<x\}$.

In other words, if you have a rule for defining $f(x)$ given $x$ and the values of $f(y)$ for all $y<x$, then this defines a unique function on all of $X$.  For instance, you can use this on Pascal's triangle with $X=\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{N}^2:b\leq a\}$ where you say $(a,b)<(c,d)$ iff $c=a+1$ and $d$ is either $b$ or $b+1$ (i.e., $(a,b)$ is one of the two spots above $(c,d)$ in the triangle).  The rule $F$ would then be to define $f(0,0)=1$, and otherwise define $f(c,d)$ to be the sum of all the values $f(a,b)$ such that $(a,b)<(c,d)$.

> *Proof of Theorem*: Say that a subset $I\subseteq X$ is an *initial segment* if $x\in I$ and $y<x$ implies $y\in I$.  Note that if $I$ is an initial segment of $X$, then there exists at most one function $f$ on $I$ satisfying $f(x)=F(x,f|_{I(x)})$ for each $x\in I$ (given two such functions, by well-foundedness there is a minimal element on which they disagree, which then gives a contradiction).  Call such a function *good*.  Now let $S$ be the set of all such good functions defined on initial segments of $X$ (this is a set by Replacement), and let $f=\bigcup S$.  Note that if $g,h\in S$ then $g$ and $h$ agree on $\operatorname{dom}(g)\cap\operatorname{dom}(h)$ since there is at most one good function on that set, and so $f$ is a function.  The domain of $f$ is an initial segment of $X$ (since it is a union of initial segments), and $f$ is good since if $x\in\operatorname{dom}(f)$, there is some $g\in S$ such that $x\in\operatorname{dom}(g)$ and then $f$ and $g$ agree on $I(x)$ and also on $x$.
>
> To complete the proof, it remains to be shown that $f$ is in fact defined on all of $X$.  Suppose it is not; then there is a minimal element $x\in X$ where $f$ is not defined.  This means $f$ is defined on $I(x)$.  But now we can extend $f$ to a good function $f'$ on $\operatorname{dom}(f)\cup\{x\}$ by defining $f'(x)=F(x,f|_{I(x)})$.  This $f'$ is then in $S$, contradicting the definition of $f$.  Thus $f$ must be defined on all of $X$.

That said, your idea of partitioning your set is a natural and useful one, and is called the *rank* with respect to a well-founded relation.  Here is one way to define it.

> **Definition**: Let $X$ be a set and let $<$ be a well-founded relation on $X$.  We then recursively define a function $\operatorname{rank}:X\to Ord$ as follows: $\operatorname{rank}(x)=\sup\{\operatorname{rank}(y)+1:y<x\}$.  (Note that such a recursive definition makes sense using the Theorem above.)

So, $\operatorname{rank}(x)=0$ if $x$ is minimal, $\operatorname{rank}(x)=1$ if $x$ is not minimal but all its predecessors are minimal, and so on.  Your sets $A_k$ are exactly the elements of rank $k$.  In general, though, the rank of an element may not be finite (in other words, you would need to continue your process transfinitely in order to exhaust your set).  For instance, if $X$ is well-ordered, then the rank function is just the unique isomorphism from $X$ to an ordinal.

Now, how can you use rank to make recursive definitions?  Well, just observe that if you define $x\prec y$ to mean that $\operatorname{rank}(x)<\operatorname{rank}(y)$, then $\prec$ is also a well-founded relation on $X$ (indeed, this uses only the fact that $\operatorname{rank}$ is some function to the ordinals!).  So, using the Theorem, you can recursively define functions on $X$ by defining $f(x)$ in terms of the values of $f(y)$ for all $y$ of lower rank than $x$.

Comment: This is amazing! Could you recommend a reference on this stuff? I can't seem to find much online about order theory.

Comment: I don't really know a reference, but I imagine any decent introduction to axiomatic set theory will discuss this in some form.  In particular, this general notion of recursion and rank are *very* important in set theory when applied to the relation $\in$.

Comment: To double check that I understand the notion of rank correctly, for instance, in $\{1-\frac 1n : n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{1\},$ we have $\operatorname{rank}(1) = \omega+1$?

Comment: Not quite: the rank would be $\omega$, since all of the smaller numbers have finite rank.

Comment: Look, Eric, I'm not as active these days to get so much incoming reputation that I can afford to be giving you a bounty every two days. You're just being unreasonable!

Comment: Technically isn't the signature of $F$ supposed to be $X\times V^{I(x)} \to V$?

Comment: @LukeCollins: I mean, $V^{I(x)}$ is a subclass of $V$.

Comment: Why is that the case? My understanding of the term "class" is an object which can contain sets (and not other classes).

Comment: @LukeCollins Every element of $V^{I(x)}$ is a set, since it's a function whose domain is a set.

Comment: Yes, but why is $V^{I(x)}$ a subclass of $V$? Doesn't the former contain pairs $(i,v)$ where $i\in I(x)$ and $v\in V$?

Comment: @LukeCollins: *Every* class is a subclass of $V$.  $V$ is the class of all sets.

Comment: @EricWofsey Oohh, $V$ is the "universe", of course.

Comment: @Eric uniqueness of $f$ doesn't follow with your definition of initial segment. Suppose that $f(r)\neq g(r)$ and $f(x)=g(x)$ for $x<r$ then it doesn't follows from here a contradiction as $f|_{I(r)}$ and $g|_{I(r)}$ are already different because $r\in I(r)$. However you can fix it defining initial segments as strict, that is, $x\in I(y)\Leftrightarrow x<y$, then uniqueness follow from here

Comment: @Masacroso: That *is* my definition of $I(y)$.

Comment: @Eric I didn't noticed that you defined initial segment twice, however your second definition is wrong. You wrote "Say that a subset $I\subseteq X$ is an *initial segment* if $x\in I$ and $y<x$ implies $y\in I$." If this would be true then $[0,1]$ will be an initial segment in $[0,\infty )$ but this is wrong.

Comment: @Masacroso: Why is that wrong?  The term "initial segment" is probably sometimes used with different meanings; I'm just defining a meaning of it for the purpose of this proof.

Comment: @Eric as I said in my first theorem this second definition is clearly wrong as you can't use it to prove the uniqueness of $f$

Comment: @Masacroso: I don't know what you mean.  Perhaps this will clear up the confusion: I give two completely separate definitions: one definition of the notation "$I(x)$" and another definition of the term "initial segment".  These are not the same thing.